# 'Net Use' Command Works in Win 7 but not XP. Why?

Tags: windows-7, networking, command-line, batch

I wrote a script to dynamically map drives for our users.  The script it generates is a simple 'net use' command that looks like this:

net use * https://oursite.com/bobs_stuff

This works perfectly fine in Windows 7 but in XP I get: "System error 67 has occurred.  The network name cannot be found".

I've done some searches but haven't found much.  The only progress I made (if you want to call it that) is that I dropped the 's' in the http on XP and it connects, asks for my username/password and then fails.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

**Update**

I am trying to connect to a WebDAV server.  I can do this manually in XP by creating a new network place; however, I need to be able to do this from a command prompt so I can script this automatically.

Comment: Answer to update: I've tried this a while ago. If the webdav server has a http address, then it can be done in XP. Otherwise you're out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`net use` in XP cannot use HTTPS addresses when assigning to a drive letter.

This limitation does not exist in Vista and above.

**Edit:**
it is possible though to use SSL-connections via "Web Folder" functionality in XP:

http://www.queensu.ca/its/qshare/tutorials/webdav/webdav-winxp.html

Comment: Hmm...any work-around outside taking away ssl?

Comment: I updated my original post.

Comment: There's "MapNetworkDrive" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kst88h6%28VS.85%29.aspx) for VBScript, but it does the same thing as "net use".

Comment: Thanks.  Doesn't look like I can get this done in XP.